# PHP contact form doesn't send, but will redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect

So, here's the situation:

I am using some simple php to send a contact form. It works fine if I end the php with:

```
echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

but if I try and redirect to a custom html page, the redirect works but the email never sends.

```
    header('Location: thankyou.htm');

exit;
```

Here's the full code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('comments')->maxLength(6000);




$pp->sendEmailTo('exa@eax.co'); 



header('Location: thankyou.htm');
exit;
```

Comment: Setting a redirect header will have no bearing whatsoever on whether your email gets sent. They are totally unrelated. You potentially have a different issue which was coincidentally introduced at the  same time as you introduced the redirect. Do some more detailed debugging.

Comment: it's literally the only change I made. When I swap between the two the situation repeats.

Comment: The email sending happens before the header is even sent. It seems impossible it could affect it. Turn on PHP error logging (so you can still see errors and warnings in a file even when the redirection is occurring) and see if anything is logged.